# Casting inherited template class to parent class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

edit: Added the cast-problem.

---

I have a small C++ problem and hope you can help me with it.
I'm using a library that provides a class `GenericHandler`. I have to inherit from that class, override stuff and then register my handler with the library to get the magic running. As I need multiple handlers that overlap in some areas, I tried to use templates as follows

```cpp
template <typename T>
class MyGenericHandler : public GenericHandler
{
// everything used for all handlers goes here
};

class MyIntHandler : public MyGenericHandler<int>
{
};

class MyFloatHandler : public MyGenericHandler<float>
{
};

// in main
std::shared_ptr<MyIntHandler> handler = std::make_shared<MyIntHandler>();
library::HandlerQueue.register(handler);
// error-message: "no viable conversion from shared_ptr<MyIntHandler> to shared_ptr<GenericHandler>.
// Same error if I try it like this:
std::shared_ptr<GenericHandler> handler = std::make_shared<MyIntHandler>();
```

However, I now can't cast `MyIntHandler` into the library provided `GenericHandler` anymore.
It did work before, when I had `MyIntHandler : public GenericHandler`, so I guess the template somehow broke stuff.
Is there a way to still get it working? Do I need to cast manually, if yes how would I best do that?

Comment: What do you mean by that you "can't cast"? Please, provide the minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem and the error message you are getting.

Comment: Where is `GenericHandler`?

Comment: See edit.
The GenericHandler is provided by the library I use, so it's not implemented by me.
I tried to keep the example simple, if you need a fully functional, running one I can put that together for you too. :) @DanielLangr

Comment: I can't reproduce the error: https://godbolt.org/z/n4Mhn9T8z

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed by using `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` it seems; still unsure why @prehistoricpenguin couldn't reproduce it though.